# How do I run a GET/POST and JSON RESULT on a page?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I have a page that does a JSON result, get and post method in the controller with two submit buttons.  One button goes to the Post method only for a redirect, and the other button goes to the JsonResult method(named AddTableData).  How do I set this up in my JQuery code?

```
$('#firstSubmit').click(function() {
    $(document).submit(function() {
    });
});

$('#secondSubmit').click(function() {
    $('#addTable').submit(function() {
        $.post($(this).attr("action"), $(this).serialize(), function(response) {
            ...load Table
        });
        return false;
    });
});

<%using (Html.BeginForm("LoadTable", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "addTable" })) %>
    <td><input id="Submit1" type="submit" name="firstSearch" value="Search" /></td>
    <td><input id="Submit2" type="submit" name="secondSearch" value="Search" /></td>
```

How do I use the firstSubmit to hit the post only, and the second submit to work the JsonResult only?

**EDIT**

```
$('#secondSubmit').click(function() {
    $.getJSON("Home/AddTableData", {Name:"Name on Document"}, function(json) {
        alert("good");
    });
});
```

My variables that usually get picked up on a get/post function is gone.  How do I post them to my JSon function?

Comment: @treeface - see Edit. That is what I have for my submit button and the using for my form, but the get/post is on the Index.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#firstSubmit').click(function() {
  $('#addTable').submit();
});

$('#secondSubmit').click(function() {
  $.getJSON("Home/AddTableData", $('#addTable').serialize(), function(json) {
    alert("good");
  });
});


<%using (Html.BeginForm("LoadTable", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "addTable" })) %>
<td><input id="Submit1" type="button" name="firstSearch" value="Search" /></td>
<td><input id="Submit2" type="button" name="secondSearch" value="Search" /></td>
```

Comment: I never thought about that.  I am not going to my JsonResult method however (AddTableData).  Is there away to redirect there?

Comment: i m sorry didnt get you,, could u explain further,

Comment: I think I am getting closer.  I am getting to the JsonResult method, but the variables I usually pass from my form is now null.  Do you know how to do that?  See my New Edits

Answer (score 2):

Assuming I am understanding you correctly I have 2 answers for you...

1. Why use JavaScript just to post a form without Ajax?
2. If you must post the form using JavaScript, submit the form, not the document, so something like:

   `$('form').submit();`

Comment: The form is being posted to the JSonResult. "addTable.  The post is on the Index method controller.

Comment: You are correct. I made that correction and is now using one as a submit type and the other as a button.  That takes care of the problem. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested this:

```
$('#secondSubmit').click(function() {
    $url = 'Home/AddTableData/?'+$('#add_table').children('input').serialize()
    $.getJSON($url, {Name:"Name on Document"}, function(json) {
        alert("good");
    });
});
```